# User in Passport Authentication Custom Callback is always false

Tags: express, callback, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to use local authentication with Passport and Express, and I have two separate routes to log in: one for the website, which does a redirect, and one for the mobile app which I want to return a JSON object.  The redirect route works.  However, POSTing the same username and password to the other route receives the JSON response for a failed login.  My LocalStrategy is as follows:

```
passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy(
  {passReqToCallback : true},
  function(req, username, password, done) {
    funct.localAuth(username, password)
    .then(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        console.log("LOGGED IN AS: " + user.username);
        req.session.success = 'You are successfully logged in ' + user.username + '!';
        return done(null, user);
      }
      if (!user) {
        console.log("COULD NOT LOG IN");
        req.session.error = 'Could not log user in. Please try again.'; //inform user could not log them in
        return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
      }
    })
    .fail(function (err){
      console.log(err.body);
      return done(err);
    });
  }
));
```

and these are the two places I use it:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-signin', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/signin'
  })
);

app.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local-signin', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(user);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json(true);
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      return res.json(user);
    });
  })
  (req, res, next);
});
```

I get the success redirect from './login', but './api/login' replies with 'true' (the JSON response I have set for if 'user' is 'false').  This doesn't make any sense to me, but I can't find any problem with the code.

Any idea what the issue here could be? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the values of Error and User??

Comment: res.json(user) results in 'false'; I didn't check err (should've), or try looking at user from the server end.  But I returned to the project this week and it turns out that I was mis-formatting the POST data on Postman; oops.